# Quotient Rule X Chain Rule Question

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives

I’m given a question that uses both the chain rule and product rule. I manged to do the chain rule part which was ok. But when it got to the product rule things got more serious. I subbed in the relevant terms, expanded them and now I split them up. I attempted to cancel them down but when I look at the answer my right-hand side was in correct. I put $2\sin2x\cdot e^x\sin x$ but that was unfortunately incorrect. So, I’m asking for your help to tell me how to completely cancel this down.
Thanks
~Neamus

[image: juicy question]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the derivative of $$\frac {e^x \sin x}{\cos 2x}$$
I got for the whole derivative (using the chain rule and product rule)
$$\frac {\cos 2x (e^x (\sin x \cos x) + \sin x (e^x)) - e^x \sin x (-2 \sin 2x) }{\cos ^2 2x}$$

This equals $$\frac {\cos 2x (e^x (\sin x \cos x) + \sin x (e^x))}{\cos ^2 2x} -
 \frac {e^x \sin x (-2 \sin 2x)}{\cos^2 2x}$$

For the left hand side: $$\frac {\cos 2x (e^x (\sin x \cos x) + \sin x (e^x)}{\cos ^2 2x} \rightarrow \frac{e^x (\sin x \cos x) + \sin x (e^x)}{\cos 2x}$$

For the right hand side: $$\frac {e^x \sin x (-2 \sin 2x)}{\cos^2 2x} \rightarrow \frac {-2 e^x \sin x \sin 2x}{\cos ^2 2x} \rightarrow \frac {-2 e^x \sin x \tan 2x}{\cos 2x}$$

Combining both together and factoring...

$$\frac {e^x(\sin x \cos x) + e^x \sin x}{\cos 2x} + \frac {2e^x \sin x \tan 2x}{cos 2x} \rightarrow {\frac {e^x \sin x (\cos x + 1)+2 \tan 2x}{\cos 2x}} $$

EDIT: This can be simplified further to

$$\tan 2x (\frac {e^x}{2} + 2 \sec 2x) + e^x \sin x \sec 2x$$

If this needs further simplification or if I'm incorrect anywhere, let me know.

Comment: How did you get -2e^xsinxsin2x when you split them up? is there a rule im missing

Comment: I made corrections to the above...I actually had the quotient rule backwards on top of it all.